# PHP class recursion

Tags: php, oop, recursion

I want to ask if recursion in PHP objects is treated well and if is acceptable overall. Because I would rather have this

```
class Human{

    public $pet;

    function setPet($pet){
        $this->pet = $pet;
    }

}

class Pet{
    public $owner;

    function __construct($owner){
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
}

$a = new Human();
$b = new Pet($a);

$a->setPet($b);
```

Than an array of users, then store the pet's owner as ID and in the occasion that I need to fetch the pet's owner I would need to do something like

```
$arrayOfUsers[$pet->owner]
```

Which as you see is definitely not pretty. Is this kind of recursion memory-saving in comparison to other methods? Is it safe and is it good practice?

Comment: Those are called "circular dependencies". And they are considered to a mistake in ones code.

Comment: That is not recursion. That's simply one object embedding another. Recursion is when a chain of function/method calls end up calling themselves again. e.g. `function foo() { foo(); }`

Comment: @tereško if this is considered a mistake, how is this functionality achieved the right way? I mean accessing a pet's owner, if I cant reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with [Recursion](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/6.RECURSION.html).
If a Human has a pet then a Pet cannot have a Human, otherwise you will create a circular dependency which is a bad practice.

If you want to be able to find the pet's owner having only the pet, the you can try this.

1 Remove Pet from human.

```
class Human{
    public $field1;
    public $field2; 
    //etc
}
```

2 Add the Owner's id to the pet

```
class Pet{
   public $owner_id;

   function __construct($owner_id){
       $this->owner_id = $owner_id;
   }
}

    $owner = new Human();
    $pet = new Pet($owner->get_id());
```

This allows you to :

1. If you only have the owner (Human) and you want to retrieve the pests just use the owner_id to run a look up on the pet's table.
2. If you only have the pet and you want to retried the owner (Human), then just use the owner_id to run a look up on the owner's (Human) table.

However I must point out that in this approach the relationships between the 2 classes is not so clear. 
If you look at the Human class alone you cannot tell how does it relate to the Pet class. So I believe there must be a better way of doing this

Comment: I assumed it was recursion because `var_dump` said so.